# CSS, Once hovered keep changes

Tags: html, css, mousehover

I am using CSS for a nice overflow effect.

So if I hover an image it fades to another images with this code:

```
#image{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 400px;
background-image: url('xerath.png');
-o-transition:color .1s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
-ms-transition:color .1s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
-moz-transition:color .1s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
-webkit-transition:color .1s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
/* ...and now override with proper CSS property */
transition:color .1s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
}

#image:hover{
background-image: url('riven.png');
}
```

But now if I hover the image it changes, when i turn my mouse off the image it changes back, I don't want it to change back.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for this ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with CSS alone. You'll need some JS.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZuEC/ There it is, if you move your mouse fast over the image you see its a little bit buggy i dont want that :D

Comment: If its possible where to put JS and what JS>

Comment: Yeah i know, but i cant write JS so can someone help me out so it doesnt buggy :?

Comment: Can't you trigger it with an animation?

Comment: With jQuery:  http://jsbin.com/pezeponu/1/edit

Comment: You can do a inline coding with javascript(library) using the following elements it gives much more control
onmouseover, onmouseout, onmousedown, onmouseup

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible solutions.

**CSS only**

Move your transitions to the `:hover` and add

```
-webkit-transition-duration:10000s;
   -moz-transition-duration:10000s;
    -ms-transition-duration:10000s;
     -o-transition-duration:10000s;
        transition-duration:10000s;
```

to `#image`. This makes the image transition back so slowly that it appears like the image keeps the changes.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/zadTY/)**

**With JavaScript**

Add an event listener for `mouseover` to the image and apply a class to `#image` which keeps the changes.

JavaScript

```
document.querySelector("#image").addEventListener("mouseover",function() {
    this.classList.add("transitioned");
});
```

CSS

```
#image.transitioned {
    background-image: url('http://g2f.nl/07vbp18');
}
```

**[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/zadTY/2/)**

Comment: That second with JS works really nice! But i want when i put my mouse on it again it changes back, is that possible somehow?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/zadTY/4/ :)

Comment: But now its buggy if you mover your mouse really fast over it

Comment: Someone that knows how to fix the buggy thing? Because when you move your mouse quick over it it buggs. Or is it maybe possible to change the background-image of the div every 5 seconds or something?

Comment: This one should work: http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/zadTY/6/
But I don't know if it's the best solution possible. If everyone has a better idea, please let me know!